# jQuery validator custom regex fails

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am using the jQuery validator plugin and i need to apply custom validation on a specific field.

What I need to validate is that it begins with a J must be followed by 1-3 digits in the range between 1 and 999.

> **Valid regex**:     J1, J10, J599
>
> **Invalid regex**:   H1, H10, H599

I have come up with this regex but it fails.  I get an alert saying 'failed':

```
/^[J]{1}\d{1,3}$/
```

I test it like this:

```
if($('#bin').valid()) {
    //passed
}
else {
    alert('failed');
}
```

I have also added a rule:

```
$("#bin").rules("add", {
    regexp: /^[J]{1}\d{1,3}$/,
    required: true
});
```

and tried each of these 3 addMethod()s but I still can't get it to work

```
//this fails validation
$.validator.addMethod(
    "bin",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please scan/enter a valid bin number."
);


//this fails validation
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Please scan/enter a valid bin number.");

//this fails validation
$.validator.addMethod('regexp', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(param);
},'Please scan/enter a valid bin number.');
```

Comment: your code contains : */

Comment: That's because it didn't work. In fact none of them work

Comment: can you edit your code and can you give jsfiddle ?

Comment: It's the regex that fails not the code. Just tried this /^[a-z]{1,10}$/ and put in adrock and it passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was causing the problem.

It was the regex like I thought it was.

Changed

```
$("#bin").rules("add", {
    regexp: /^[J]{1}\d{1,3}$/,
    required: true
});
```

to

```
$("#bin").rules("add", {
    regexp: /^([jJ]{1}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|999)$/,
    required: true }
);
```

Comment: Remove the `|999` part, it makes the regex match `999`. Also, `{1}` is useless.